# If two continuous functions agree on a cofinite set of reals, are they equal?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C$ be the set of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If two functions in $C$ agree everywhere except possibly on a finite set, do they in fact agree everywhere?

Comment: Yes, because $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff and finite sets have empty interior.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider their difference if the functions disagree with each other on a finite set then the difference will be discontinuous but the difference of continuous functions is continuous .